# How to hide columns in Kendo Grid when editing in a popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I use Telerik Kendo Grid editing-inline.

I want to hide certain columns when editing popup the number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [edit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit) event of the grid to hide some element from the popup window:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    edit: function(e) {
        e.container.find(".k-edit-label:first").hide();
        e.container.find(".k-edit-field:first").hide();
    }
});
```